# How to update a page with new widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a grocery list app in Flutter, since I'm pretty new, and I am basically trying to make the page such that it asks you how many ingredient's you'll have, and then it will display that many `Row` widgets, which each contain two `TextFields`. One is for the actual ingredient, and the other is for the number of that ingredient. Here is the relevant code:

```
                    child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      controller: numOfIngs,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: '#',
                          hintText: '#'),
                      onSubmitted: (numIngredients) {
                        debugPrint(numIngredients);
                        TextEditingController controller =
                            TextEditingController();
                        TextEditingController numcontroller =
                            TextEditingController();
                        setState(() {
                          return ListOfIngs(controller, numcontroller, 1);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
```

Also, here is the `ListOfIngs` class, which I am hoping will create the actual rows of `textFields`:

```
class ListOfIngs extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  ListOfIngs(TextEditingController controller,
      TextEditingController numcontroller, int i);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController controller;
    TextEditingController numcontroller;
    int i;
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Ingredient $i',
            ),
            onSubmitted: (ing) {
              _newListIngs.add(controller);
            }),
        TextField(
            controller: numcontroller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: '#', labelText: '#'),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onSubmitted: (numIng) {
              _newlistnumIngs.add(numcontroller);
            }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I don't think that I am going about this the right way, and I am hoping someone out there has some idea of how to create this. Thanks, RiverRipple

Comment: Can you add the code of `_newListIngs` ?

Comment: _newListIngs and _newListnumIngs are both just Lists of TextEditingController for the TextFields